# Joining lists which can have the last entry repeated

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, join

I have a set of lists, which may or may not have something in common.

For example:

```
 v1=[a,b,[1]]
 v2=[b,c,[3]]
 v3=[c,d,[1]]
 v4=[a,f,[2]]
```

and I want to join some of these lists using the following rule:

If the "normal" entries of two lists x and y differ only by the first and last normal entry respectively, then I could join them.

In this example when comparing v1 and v2, we see that the first normal entry of v1 (a) is not a normal entry of v2, and the last normal entry of v2 (c) is not a normal entry of v1, so I would like to join v1 and v2 and obtain the following result:

```
 v=[a,b,c,[1],[3]]
```

but note that we could use the same analogy with v2 and v3, that is, v2 and v3 only differ by the first and last normal entry respectively (I know that I am referring to the last entry as the second one here, but there is a reason for this, since there may be some complexity to this problem added). When we join v2 and v3 we obtain:

```
 w=[b,c,d,[3],[1]]
```

There is just one last thing that I would like to do, after following this reasoning. We see that I have not mentioned v4 because it doesn't satisfies the rule, but if we take a careful look at the new lists printed out, we see that v and w follow the rule, that is, v and w only differ by the first and last normal entry respectively, so we could join them (the first normal entry of v is "a" and the last normal entry of w is "d"). When we join them, we obtain:

```
x=[a,b,c,d,[1],[3],[1]]
```

Here, we see that the normal entries cannot be repeated for the same list, but the other entries can be repeated.

The lists I would like to be printed out following this reasoning and including the original ones of only two normal entries are:

```
v1=[a,b,[1]]
v2=[b,c,[3]]
v3=[c,d,[1]]
v4=[a,f,[2]]
v=[a,b,c,[1],[3]]
w=[b,c,d,[3],[1]]
x=[a,b,c,d,[1],[3],[1]]
```

I really appreciate any help given. I believe we should define a function and use loops, and I know how to join lists, but when following these conditions, I literally don't see how to start it out.